# A/C Fan Speeds Working on High and Low only on 2004 Mercury Grand Marquis LS

Tags: ac, mercury, heater-blower

On my 2004 Mercury Grand Marquis, the blower just started working on only two speeds, high and low.  Recently the blower suddenly quit working altogether and it was the resister.  What's the best take on this problem; could it be as simple as the fan switch?  (The system is the auto climate control.)

Comment: Yeah, I know that issue. That should be a heating resistance module. Sticks somewhere in the air flow. Not sure about Mercury.

Answer (score 1):

Resistor packs/Thermostats can and do fail. Your one lasted 10 years. This would not be a bad performance for non-safety critical part.